# Unable to send email using git send-email

Tags: git, smtp, gmail, git-send-email

I am not able to send patches using git send-email.
This is my .gitconfig file

```
[user]
    email = my-email
    name = my-name
[sendemail]
    smtpencryption = tls
    smtpserver = smtp.gmail.com
    smtpuser = my-email
    smtpserverport = 587
    smtppassword = mypassword
```

Here mypassword is my google account's app password and not the real one.
What is wrong in the configuration?

This is how I am trying to use the command :

```
git send-email 0001-patch-name.patch
```

This is the error:

> Unable to initialize SMTP properly. Check config and use --smtp-debug. VALUES: server=smtp.gmail.com encryption=tls hello=madhuparna-HP-Notebook port=587 at /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-email line 1506.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Unable to initialize SMTP properly." when using using git send-email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038662/how-to-solve-unable-to-initialize-smtp-properly-when-using-using-git-send-ema)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out, the problem was not with the configuration but it was because of firewall issues.